# Unable to mark a directory as test sources root in PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I was trying to mark a directory as test sources root in PyCharm so that I don't have to manually set the target directory for my generated test file every time. When I right-click my "tests" directory I only see the following four options:

Mark Directory As:
1. Source Root
2. Template Folder
3. Excluded
4. Resource Root

I remember doing this in Intellij for Java but is this not possible for PyCharm?

Answer (score 21):

Do the following:

1. Mark the directory as "sources".
2. Close PyCharm.
3. Open the `<project root>/.idea/<projectname>.iml` file in a text editor.
4. Search for "isTestSource=" for the appropriate directories and change it from "false" to "true".
5. Reopen PyCharm.

Comment: I confirm this works and my tests route is now green whereas src root is blue in Pycharm. However, I was able to import my tests module inside src modules as well so I'm not sure if it really helps distinguish between src and tests modules

Comment: this works without having to restart PyCharm as well (v2021.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for a late answer, but I tracked this down while searching for a separate answer.  I don't know when JetBrains updated this, but now you can mark a directory as a Test Sources Root from the PyCharm GUI.  However, you have to first do a "Mark Directory as/Sources Root".  Then if you right click on that directory, and choose "Mark Directory as" you will get "Test Sources Root" as an option.

Answer (score -2):

To keep the UI simpler, the test source root configuration option is not exposed in the PyCharm UI.

Comment: Is there any way to dig it up?

Comment: You can try to modify the .iml file inside the .idea directory and change isTestSource="false" to isTestSource="true". Not entirely sure whether this will affect the "Create tests" action.

Answer (score -3):

In PyCharm 2017.1.3
From the tests toolbar, click **edit configurations** then you can set the working directory default, this will be used by each test on first run.

[image: Tests toolbar]

[image: Where to configure PyCharm's default test working directory]

Hope this helps!

Comment: the question is about the location of the test source code, not about the working directory if tests gets executed.

Comment: @guettli to be fair, I sometimes use this as a workaround.