# How to generate unit tests for Python using src and test folder structure (preferable with PyCharm integration)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, pytest, code-generation

In my python project I have following folder structure:

```
src
  foo
    foo.py
  baa
    baa.py
test
  foo
  baa
```

and would like to **generate a unit test file** `test/foo/test_foo.py` that tests `src/foo/foo.py`.

In PyCharm I can

- go somewhere in foo.py and
- use the key combination `Ctrl+Shift+T` and
- select the option "Create new test".

That generates a new test file and initializes it with some test method. Also see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-tests.html

However:

- PyCharm does not automatically detect the wanted target directory `test/foo` but suggests to use the source directory `src/foo` instead. That would result in a test file located in the same folder as the tested file.
- The key combination does not work for files/modules that do not contain a class or function but just provide a property.
- PyCharm generates unwanted **init**.py files.

Therefore the built in unit test generation of PyCharm does not work for me.

**=> What is the recommended way to generate unit tests for Python?**

I also tried to use [UnitTestBot](https://github.com/UnitTestBot) or [pynguin](https://github.com/se2p/pynguin) but was not able to generate corresponding test files. Creating all the folders and files manually would be a tedious task and I hoped that a modern IDE would do (parts of) the job for me.

You might argue that test should be written first. Therefore, if there is an option to do it the other way around and generate the tested files from exiting tests... that would also be helpful.

Another option might be to go for [GitHub Copilot](https://dev.to/this-is-learning/copilot-chat-writes-unit-tests-for-you-1c82). However, I am not allowed to use it at work and do not want to send our code to a remote server. Therefore, I am still looking for a more conservative approach.

A different approach would be a custom script that loops through the existing src folder structure and at least creates corresponding folders and files in the test folder. I was hoping for an existing solution but could not find one, yet.

**Related:**

https://github.com/UnitTestBot/UTBotJava/issues/2670

https://github.com/se2p/pynguin/issues/52

[Can pytest or any testing tool in python generate the unit test automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273333/can-pytest-or-any-testing-tool-in-python-generate-the-unit-test-automatically)

https://www.strictmode.io/articles/using-github-copilot-for-testing

https://dev.to/this-is-learning/copilot-chat-writes-unit-tests-for-you-1c82

Comment: From the documentation you site, the "Create test" dialog contains a "Target directory" field.  Just set that to where you want the test file to go.  No?

Comment: I have double checked and that works.

Comment: What I haven't worked out is why the "Target directory" doesn't default to the directory you have identified with "Mark Directory as/Source Root - Mark Directory as/Test Sources Root" (you have to do it in two steps).

Comment: Sorry.  I misread the question.  I see that this is actually your real question.

Comment: Hm. PyCharm does not have an option to mark test folders. Maybe thats part of the issue. However, even if I manually mark it as test folder, the target directory is not automatically identified. Manually specifying the directory for each new test file would be annoying.  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205805519/comments/115000256484

Comment: PyCharm can mark directories as Test Sources Root.  I am not sure when this was added.  It is a bit obscure.  You just have to do it as a two step process.  First you right click on the directory and choose "Mark Directory as/Source Root".  Then when you right on the directory and choose "Mark Directory as", the "Test Sources Root" option is visible.  Unfortunately even if you do that PyCharm does not default to that directory in the Create New Test dialog.

Comment: I have added that process as an answer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421625/unable-to-mark-a-directory-as-test-sources-root-in-pycharm

Answer (score 1):

Below is a first draft for a script that generates a unit test skeleton for missing test files. I asked AI to generate that script for me and refactored it a bit.

```
import inspect
import os


def main():
    src_dir = 'src'
    test_dir = 'test'
    generate_unit_test_skeleton(src_dir, test_dir)


def generate_unit_test_skeleton(src_dir, test_dir):
    # Loop over all folders and files in src directory
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
        # Get the relative path of the current folder or file
        relative_folder_path = os.path.relpath(root, src_dir)

        # Create the corresponding unit test folder in test directory
        test_folder = generate_test_folder_if_not_exists(relative_folder_path, test_dir)

        # Loop over all files in the current folder
        for file in files:
            # Check if the file has a .py extension
            if file.endswith('.py'):
                generate_unit_tests_for_file(
                    file,
                    relative_folder_path,
                    test_folder,
                )


def generate_unit_tests_for_file(
    file,
    relative_directory,
    test_directory,
):
    # Create the corresponding unit test file in test directory
    generated_test_file_path = generate_unit_test_file(
        file,
        relative_directory,
        test_directory,
    )

    if generated_test_file_path is not None:
        # Get all classes and functions defined in the original file
        classes, functions = determine_members(file, relative_directory)

        # Generate test functions for each class and function
        generate_test_functions(
            file,
            generated_test_file_path,
            classes,
            functions,
        )


def generate_test_functions(
    file,
    test_file_path,
    classes,
    functions,
):
    module_name = determine_module_name(file)

    with open(test_file_path, 'a') as test_file:
        for class_name, class_instance in classes:
            generate_test_function_for_class(
                test_file,
                module_name,
                class_name,
                class_instance,
            )

        for function_name, function_instance in functions:
            generate_test_function_for_function(
                test_file,
                module_name,
                function_name,
                function_instance,
            )


def generate_test_function_for_function(
    test_file,
    module_name,
    function_name,
    function_instance,
):
    # Generate the test function name
    test_function_name = f'test_{function_name}'
    arguments = determine_arguments(function_instance)

    # Write the test function to the test file
    test_file.write(f'def {test_function_name}():\n')
    test_file.write(f'    # TODO: Implement test\n')
    test_file.write(f'    # result = {module_name}.{function_name}({arguments})\n')
    test_file.write(f'    pass\n')
    test_file.write('\n')


def generate_test_function_for_class(
    test_file,
    module_name,
    class_name,
    class_instance,
):
    # Generate the test function name
    test_function_name = f'test_{class_name}'

    arguments = determine_arguments(class_instance)

    # Write the test function to the test file
    test_file.write(f'def {test_function_name}():\n')
    test_file.write(f'    # TODO: Implement test\n')
    test_file.write(f'    # instance = {module_name}.{class_name}({arguments})\n')
    test_file.write(f'    pass\n')
    test_file.write('\n')


def determine_members(file, relative_directory):
    # Get the module name
    module_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]

    # Import the module
    directory_import_path = relative_directory.replace('\\', '.')
    import_path = f'{directory_import_path}.{module_name}'
    module = __import__(import_path, fromlist=[module_name])

    # Get all classes and functions defined in the module
    classes = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass)
    functions = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)
    return classes, functions


def determine_arguments(function_instance):
    try:
        signature = inspect.signature(function_instance)
    except ValueError:
        return ''

    parameters = signature.parameters

    arguments = []
    for param in parameters.values():
        argument = determine_argument(param)
        arguments.append(argument)

    argument_string = ', '.join(arguments)
    if len(arguments) > 2:
        argument_string += ','  # leading comma causes line breaks if formatted with black
    return argument_string


def determine_argument(param):
    argument = param.name
    if param.default != inspect.Parameter.empty:
        default_value = determine_default_value(param.default)
        argument += f'={default_value}'
    return argument


def determine_default_value(default_instance):
    if inspect.isfunction(default_instance):
        return default_instance.__name__
    elif isinstance(default_instance, str):
        return f"'{default_instance}'"
    else:
        return default_instance


def generate_unit_test_file(file, relative_directory, test_directory):
    test_file_path = os.path.join(test_directory, f'test_{file}')
    if os.path.exists(test_file_path):
        return None
    else:
        # Open the test file in write mode
        with open(test_file_path, 'w') as f:
            # Write the initial import statement
            import_statement = generate_import_statement(file, relative_directory)
            f.write(import_statement)
            f.write('\n')
    return test_file_path


def generate_import_statement(file, relative_directory):
    directory_import_path = relative_directory.replace('////', '.')
    module_name = determine_module_name(file)
    statement = f'from {directory_import_path} import {module_name}\n'
    return statement


def determine_module_name(file):
    name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    return name


def generate_test_folder_if_not_exists(relative_path, test_dir):
    test_folder = os.path.join(test_dir, relative_path)
    if not os.path.exists(test_folder):
        os.makedirs(test_folder)
    return test_folder


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example result for a file 'test/foo/test_foo.py':

```
import foo.foo

def test_Language():
    # TODO: Implement test
    # instance = controls.Language(value, names=None, module=None, qualname=None, type=None, start=1, boundary=None,)
    pass

def test_Layout():
    # TODO: Implement test
    # instance = controls.Layout(kwargs)
    pass

def test_SimpleNamespace():
    # TODO: Implement test
    # instance = controls.SimpleNamespace()
    pass
```